# Cannot lauch Shinystan demo in R

Tags: r, shinyapps, stan

After having installed the shinystan 2.6.0 package in R 4.2.0, I tried to launch the model demo but the windows that should open pops and then quickly disappears, leaving the following message in the R console:

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:4995
The `name` provided ('refresh') is deprecated in Font Awesome 5:
* please consider using 'sync' or 'fas fa-sync' instead
* use the `verify_fa = FALSE` to deactivate these messages
The `name` provided ('refresh') is deprecated in Font Awesome 5:
* please consider using 'sync' or 'fas fa-sync' instead
* use the `verify_fa = FALSE` to deactivate these messages
Warning: Error in switch: unused arguments (`By model parameter` = "parameter", `Sample information` = "lp", `Treedepth information` = "treedepth", `Step size information` = "stepsize", `Divergence information` = "divergent")
  3: shiny::runApp
  2: launch
  1: shinystan::launch_shinystan_demo
```

Here is my code:

```
install.packages("shinystan")
library(shinystan)
shinystan::launch_shinystan_demo()
```

Comment: This should likely be a [bug report](https://github.com/stan-dev/shinystan/issues/).